# If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is increasing, and $\sum_n\frac{1}{f(n)}$ diverges, then $\sum_n\frac{n^{\alpha}}{f(f(n))}$ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, examples-counterexamples, arithmetic-combinatorics

Suppose $\ f:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}\ $ is increasing and $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{1}{f(n)}\ $ diverges. Then $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{\log (n)}{f(f(n))}\ $ does not necessarily diverge: for example, $\ f(n) = \left\lceil{(n+4)\log(n+4) \log(\log(n+4))}\right\rceil\ $ is a counter-example.

However, I think the following might be true, and if so, I was wondering how to approach proving it:

> Suppose $\ f:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}\ $ is increasing and $\
>  \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{1}{f(n)}\ $ diverges. Then
> $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{n^{\alpha}}{f(f(n))}\ $
> diverges for each $\ \alpha>0.$

Edit: actually, I can't even think of an $\ f(n)\ $ so that
$\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{\log^2(n)}{f(f(n))}\ $
converges.

Comment: Just to clarify: by increasing, you mean $f(n+1)>f(n)$, not just $\ge$? Regarding your last comment, there is the trivial example $f(n)=n$. And anything that increases slowly enough will do as well, such as $f(n)=n\log(n)$. Then $f(f(n))\sim n\log^2n$.

Comment: Sorry - I meant I can't think of an example such that it converges. And I'll give your first question about increasing some more thought. My point was that, maybe we can weaken the question from $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{n^{\alpha}}{f(f(n))}\ $ to $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \frac{\log^k(n)}{f(f(n))}.$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think it doesn't matter which one we have as the question can shown for "increasing" can be shown to be equivalent to the question for "strictly increasing". At least, that is my feeling, but I've been trying to prove this and I keep getting confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make use of functions with rather uneven growth. Say,
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
2\quad\text{ for }n=1,\\
4\quad\text{ for }n=2,3,\\
16\quad\text{ for }n=4\dots15,\\
256\quad\text{ for }n=16\dots255,\\
\vdots \\
2^{2^k}\;(2^{2^{k-1}}\leqslant n<2^{2^k})\\
\end{cases}$$
Note that it sends 4 to 16, and 16 to 256, and 256 to its square, and each term dwarfs the previous.

So we have *almost* $2^{2^k}$ terms of size $2^{2^k}$, hence $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ over these terms is almost 1, so the same sum to infinity diverges. On the other hand, $f(f(n))$ for the same terms is a good deal bigger - I believe, enough so to give you some leeway for your $n^\alpha$.